# How can I change the background color of my p:TabView?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

This is my p:tabView of my web page with PrimeFaces

[image]

I need that the background that contains the elements of the tab, is transparent and has the same light blue color that is above, and I need to change the lead color of the content, how could I do it?
Part of the code:

```
<p:tabView id="tabv1"
                        style="border: 0px;min-height: 300px !important;box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;" >
                        <p:tab title="Cabecera Factura" titleStyleClass="tab1"
                            rendered="true">
                            <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-noborder"
                                columnClasses="ui-g-12 ui-md-12 ui-lg-6,ui-g-12 ui-md-12 ui-lg-6">
                                <p:panel class="panelAgrupacion">
                                    <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-noborder"
                                        columnClasses="ui-g-12 ui-md-12 ui-lg-4,ui-g-12 ui-md-12 ui-lg-8">

                                        <p:outputLabel value="Codigo Grupo factura"
```